# Mudar de Tela Windows com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Boa Tarde!

Galera, estou escrevendo um script em Python utilizando a biblioteca PyAutoGui. Em determinado momento, esse script "precisa navegar entre telas", exemplo, meu script está trabalhando um relatório dentro do meu sistema TMS e precisa ir para determinada tela do Excel. Como eu poderia fazer para que meu script sempre sete a tela correta?

Lembrando, eu já consigo pegar o PID do programa, utilizando a biblioteca Psutil.

Comment: existe o módulo PyGetWindow

Answer (score 1):

Para ativar uma janela fora de foco ou minimizada, costumo utilizar a função abaixo.

O argumento 'win_name' deve ser o nome do processo/janela que se pretende maximizar.

```
def win_act(win_name):
    import win32gui
    import re

    class WindowMgr:
        """Encapsulates some calls to the winapi for window management"""

        def __init__(self):
            """Constructor"""
            self._handle = None

        def find_window(self, class_name, window_name=None):
            """find a window by its class_name"""
            self._handle = win32gui.FindWindow(class_name, window_name)

        def _window_enum_callback(self, hwnd, wildcard):
            """Pass to win32gui.EnumWindows() to check all the opened windows"""
            if re.match(wildcard,
                         str(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))) is not None:
                self._handle = hwnd

        def find_window_wildcard(self, wildcard):
            """find a window whose title matches the wildcard regex"""
            self._handle = None
            win32gui.EnumWindows(self._window_enum_callback, wildcard)

        def set_foreground(self):
            """put the window in the foreground"""
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self._handle)

    w = WindowMgr()
    for x in range(3):
        w.find_window_wildcard(f".*{win_name}*")
        w.set_foreground()
```